# Runtime Error during my implementation of BFS

Tags: c++, algorithm, runtime-error

I wrote a code that performs a BFS in a graph. But right after I give second input it crashes. What is the problem. I have tried to work around it, but it is causing the program to work more eratically.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<deque>




using namespace std;
enum color{
    white, gray, black
};

static const int nil=-2147483645;
class graph{
    public:
        int key;
        int parent;
        int dis;
        color col;

};
vector<vector<graph> > g;

int BFS(graph source, graph target){
        deque<graph> Q;
        Q.push_back(source);

    while(!Q.empty()){
            graph current=*Q.begin();
            Q.pop_front();
                if(current.key == target.key){
                return current.dis;
            }
            current.col=gray;

        for(vector<graph>::iterator m=(g[current.key-1]).begin();m!=(g[current.key-1]).end();m++){
            if ( (current.parent) != (m->key) ){
                    m->parent=current.key;
                    m->col=gray;
                    m->dis=current.dis+1;
                    Q.push_back(*m);
            }
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){
        int no_vertex;cin>>no_vertex;
        int no_edge;cin>>no_edge;
//where I think the error occurs
        for(int cnt=0;cnt!=no_edge;cnt++){
            graph temp1,temp2;
            cin>>temp1.key>>temp2.key;
            temp1.col=white;
                temp2.col=white;
            temp1.dis=0;
            temp2.dis=0;
            temp1.parent=nil;
            temp2.parent=nil;

            (g[temp1.key-1]).push_back(temp2);
             (g[temp2.key-1]).push_back(temp1);
        }
//^ error is probably between the two comments
            graph (source,target);
            cin>>source.key>>target.key;
                    source.col=white;
                target.col=white;
            source.dis=0;
            target.dis=0;
            source.parent=nil;
            target.parent=nil;

 }
```

Right after giving second(first pair of vertices of the graph)  input... Windows says this program has stopped working. Please click [here](http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/GREATESC) to see the question and sample inputs

The first line of the input contains two integers N and M. N is the number of buildings: we assume that our buildings are numbered 1,2,...,N. M is the number of pairs of buildings that the director lists as being close enough to jump from one to the other. Each of the next M lines, lines 2,...,M+1, contains a pair of integers representing a pair of buildings that are close. Line i+1 contains integers Ai and Bi, 1 ≤ Ai ≤ N and 1 ≤ Bi ≤ N, indicating that buildings Ai and Bi are close enough. The last line, line M+2 contains a pair of integers S and T, where S is the building from which the Hero starts his search and T is the building where the captive is held.

sample input

5  5

1  3

Sample Input 1:

5  5

1  3

2  3

1  2

3  5

4  5

1  4

Sample Output 1:

3

Sample Input 2:

5  3

1  3

1  2

4  5

1  4

Sample Output 2:

0

Comment: You should include example of the input you provided. Otherwise it's hard to guess what went wrong. I mean, real example of what you used, not artificial one.

Comment: http://opc.iarcs.org.in/index.php/problems/GREATESC

Comment: Please include the sample input in the question itself (or, preferably hard-code the input, so we can just run the program to see the error). But really you should be debugging your program to find the problem.

Comment: @Dukeling I have added the sample inputs and outputs please look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code g is declared as a vector of vectors. Initially it contains 0 vectors of graphs.

```
vector<vector<graph> > g;
```

You should add elements to it. Either by using push_back or .resize() with the number of vertices.

```
int main(){
        int no_vertex;cin>>no_vertex;
        int no_edge;cin>>no_edge;
        g.resize(no_vertex);
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ //fix
        ...
```

This is where your code breaks:

```
(g[temp1.key-1]).push_back(temp2);
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
(g[temp2.key-1]).push_back(temp1);
 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If you use .at you will get an exception. Ex:

```
 g.at(temp1.key-1).push_back(temp2);
```

A better approach is to use a "bag and adjacency lists" `std::unordered_map<>` (C++11), if you don't have a compiler that supports C++11 use `std::map<>` instead:

```
std::unordered_map<graph, vector<graph>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. the problem is solved. However, when I submit it on the online judge it says process aborted (SIGBART) what does it mean and why is this happening?